# How to make if statement in query to mysql from excel

Tags: mysql, excel, if-statement

I am trying to make an if statement in an excelcommand, so I only get data from rows where a column named active is equal to 0.

The following command works fine, and returns everything from my "atests" tabel on my mysql server.

```
SELECT * FROM `DrLau_MISB`.`atests` WHERE userId = ?
```

(where ? is defined in another cell)

I wan't to only get data from the rows there the column named active = 0.

is it possible to make something like this

```
SELECT * FROM `DrLau_MISB`.`atests` WHERE userId = ? AND active IS 0
```

Comment: Yes you can use the AND statement in SQL.

Comment: Dooh hehe. SELECT * FROM `DrLau_MISB`.`atests` WHERE userId = ? AND active = 0;

Comment: Up my post as useful if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `DrLau_MISB`.`atests` WHERE userId = ? AND active = 0;
```